# How can I check if route has a parameter in Symfony2?

Tags: routes, symfony-2.3

I'm use Symfony2.3 and have a route named `my_route` with path `/my/test/path/{param1}`.

If I try to generate URL for this route, I'll write something like this:

```
/** @var Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router **/
$router = ...;
$router->generate('my_route', array('param1' => 'value1')); // /my/test/path/value1
```

But, if I use a non-exists parameter in `generate` method, URL becomes `/my/test/path/value1?param2=value2`:

```
$router->generate('my_route', array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2')); // /my/test/path/value1?param2=value2
```

How can I check if `param2` exists in route?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look into the class "Symfony\Component\Routing\Route".

```
$route = $this->get('router')->getRouteCollection()->get('my_route');
$pathVariables = $route->compile()->getPathVariables()
```